# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting below error:

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available

While using Spring Boot + Thymeleaf

Code:

Application class:

```html
package com.mycom.extract;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.mycom.extract")
public class MyAppExtractionWebApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MyAppExtractionWebApplication.class, args);
 }




 
 @Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(MyAppExtractionWebApplication.class);
 }
}

pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.mycom.extract</groupId>
 <artifactId>MyApp-extraction</artifactId>
 <version>1</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>MyAppExtractionWeb</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.54</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
   
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>


</project>



SecurityConfig


package com.mycom.extract.config.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 private MyAppAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/*").fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
         .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
           .usernameParameter("ipn").passwordParameter("password")
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/login?error")
        .and()
         .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
  
   http.csrf().disable();
 }

}



WebMvcConfiguration

package com.mycom.extract.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mycom.extract" })
public class MyAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

 @Override
 public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/login");
  registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("index");
  registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
 }
}
```

Referring all same kind of post in Stackoverflow could find solution for myself.

Please suggest.

URL http://localhost:8080/MyAppExtractionWeb/

```
As I am setting up login, and authentication is handled at security config side, so once it is successful it shows home page. Hence no controller mentioned.


package com.mycom.config.security;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;*/
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import com.mycom.entity.User;
import com.mycom.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;


@Configuration
public class MyAppAuthenticationProvider  implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String SECURITY_DOMAIN = "MyApp-ldapdomain";

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        try {
            CallbackHandler handler = new UserPasswordHandler(name, password);
            LoginContext lc = new LoginContext(SECURITY_DOMAIN, handler);
            lc.login();

            if(lc.getSubject() != null) {

            User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(name);

            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = null;

            if(!user.getAuthorities().isEmpty()) {
                roles = user.getAuthorities();
            }           

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password,roles);           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: For what urls you are getting 404? and could you please post your controller class here?

Comment: Hello, URL: http://localhost:8080/MyAppExtractionWeb

Comment: my question is where is your "/MyAppExtractionWeb" endpoint? if its a angular state then what is the endpoint you are calling?

Comment: I think that this because you did not use some AuthFilter: https://github.com/eustimenko/spring-web-backend-demo/blob/master/api/src/main/java/com/spring/web/demo/api/filter/AuthFilter.java

You should create some class as above and create `@Bean` from it.

Comment: Issue found. In application.properties server.servlet-path value was wrong.